# How can I fix this error:Forbidden you don't have permission to access this resource? on AlienVault Ossim

Tags: apache

I'm working on AlienVault OSSIM server which is a SIEM.
When I'm trying to access the server by its IP address, I got this error:

[image]

I'm working on Hyper-V

I tried to modify the access rights to my directory /var/www/html/index.html but it does not work. I still have the error